# How to display y-axis in decimal scale with logarithmic scale for both y-axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two y-axes on the same figure, both on logarithmic scale. How can I show both y-axes in decimal scale?

I could only make the left side with `ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter()) and ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`, but it doesn't work for the right side.
I already tried plotting directly with Matplolib, not in Pandas, or using `ax.right_ax.yaxis`

Also, is there a way to 'manually' specify the right side y-axis?

Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fzanart/50f4841374b58abbf054719cfff2c068/raw/logSO.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='line', y='sample_size', logy=True, ax = ax)
df.plot(kind='line', y='score', logy=True, ax = ax, secondary_y=True)

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but if someone is faced with a similar problem, this is what worked for me:

`ax.right_ax.get_yaxis().set_minor_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())`

All together:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fzanart/50f4841374b58abbf054719cfff2c068/raw/logSO.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='line', y='sample_size', logy=True, ax = ax)
df.plot(kind='line', y='score', logy=True, ax = ax, secondary_y=True)

formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
ax.right_ax.get_yaxis().set_minor_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

[image]